# Convert int to bytes with variable byte length

Tags: python, go, encoding, binary, base64

Python offers to specify the length of the bytes when converting an integer to a byte representation, i.e.

```
base64.b64encode((128).to_bytes(1,'little'))
-> b'gA==
```

When attempting the same in Go, using the `binary/encode` package, I can either start with `uint16` which would give something like this:

```
buf := make([]byte, 4)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(buf, uint16(128))                                                                                                                                                                
encoded := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)
-> gAAAAA==
```

Or using `PutUvarint`

```
buf := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)
n := binary.PutUvarint(buf, num)
b := buf[:n]
encoded := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b)
-> gAE==
```

Which ends up with a longer encoding due to encoding it in a way that allows decoding without knowing the length in advance which is something I am not interested in.

So what way could I translate the Python code to Go? For 1 byte I can just use `byte(num)`, up to `num = 255` but what above it? How do I go from there? I guess I could also use `uint64` and truncate th
Which ends up with a longer encoding
Which ends up with a longer encoding e padded characters myself?

Comment: Specify the length of the coding using the [byte order](https://godoc.org/encoding/binary#ByteOrder) method name: 2: PutUint16, 4: PutUint32, 8: PutUint64. As noted int he question, use `byte(n)` for a single byte encodig.

Comment: @MuffinTop I believe `PutUint16` is for 4 bytes not 2

Comment: uint16 is 16 bits, 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that would do the same as the python code you asked for in Go:

```golang
    buf := []byte{128}
    encoded := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)
```

---

What is happening with this Go code?

```golang
buf := make([]byte, 4)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(buf, uint16(128))                                                                                                                                                                
encoded := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)
```

If you output the `buf` variable here you will see, that it contains some additional `0` bytes: `[128 0 0 0]`. When initialising the byte slice with a length of 4, it will be filled with `0`s: `[0 0 0 0]`. Then the 128 is added to the first position.

When encoding the byte slice to base64 the zero bytes will also be encoded, resulting in the different output.

---

For larger numbers than a single byte can hold, you could use this code if it doesn't need to be fast:

```golang
buf := []byte(string(rune(1052)))
```

You could also work with the approach you've taken and ignore the trailing zeros:

```golang
func encodeInt(val int) string {
    if val == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    buf := make([]byte, 8)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(buf, uint64(val))
    i := len(buf)
    for buf[i-1] == 0 {
        i--
    }
    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(buf[:i])
}
```

EDIT: corrected loop to account for 0 bytes inbetween.

Comment: Your `for` loop is wrong. You need to check from the end (i.e. start with `i = 8` and check `buf[i - 1] != 0` but stop if `i == 1` because you don't want to use `i = 0` in the end—you could test with 256 or 65536 to see what I mean).